# How can I resolve Adobe After Effects | AfterFX.exe System Error?

Tags: windows, after-effects, system-error

The code execution cannot proceed because MFPlat.DLL was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Way to do this and make sure you get the correct one is via “Add optional Features” 
1 - Right Click the Windows Logo 
2 - Choose Apps and Features 
3 - Click “Optional Features” 
4 - Press the “+” sign where it says “Add a feature” 
5 - Search for “Media Feature Pack” [image: [image]] Pick Media Feature…

Answer (score 0):

Fix the MFPlat.DLL error using PowerShell:

```
Get-WindowsCapability -online | Where-Object -Property name -like "*MediaFeaturePack*" | Add-WindowsCapability -Online
```

That should solve the issue and start Adobe After Effects successfully!

*- The Architect ;-)*

Answer (score 0):

**you should follow that steps:**

1.open setting app in your computer.
2.click on apps and features.
3.click on optional features.
4.search about that and install it "media feature pack".
5.restart pc.